# Best Object Type to Iterate through in Python

Tags: python, object, iteration

I am currently stuck with this code:

```
already_known = set()
for item in collection:
    for word in item:
        if word not in already_known: 
            already_known.add(word)
```

The basic idea is to identify if a word is already known in a collection of texts or is new. To do so, I currently iterate through a steadily increasing set.
As the set reaches high volumes (~2,000 million entries), processing becomes expensive towards the end.
My question is if there is a less expensive way or object to iterate through?

Edit:

```
Variable collection: list of lists
Variable item: list
Variable word: string
```

This code is only a snapshot of the real code. I proceed with other operations but identified the iteration through the already_known set as bottleneck.

Comment: Sets discard duplicates anyway, `already_known = set(word for item in collection for word in item)` should work.

Comment: Also creation of set from list is O(n) n-size of list

Comment: please provide an input so we  can see, maybe numpy can improve the performance

Comment: Are you sure the issue is iteration/lookup itself? If *any* data structure stores "(~2,000 million entries)", you are in the GB regime just for that one data structure. At that point you should check whether your program still operates in memory, or is pushed towards swap.

Comment: I checked that. In total, the code needs 32GB. Our PC can handle 64GB.

Comment: I am afraid there is no definitive answer we can give you, then. Sets are specifically designed for membership tests (even more so than ``dict``, which also have O(1) membership tests). If you need more performance, you should look at general purpose optimisations. In case your code is all-Python, consider to use PyPy since it is plain faster and made to JIT-compile loops. Since sets are also efficient for merges, you could also try to multi-process each file to a set, then merge the sets; further optimisations are indermediate-merges of the sets – basically doing map-reduce. ...

Comment: ... However, that is basically guess-work. Which of these work-or-not depend on your data distribution, your HW and soft factors (e.g. how you weight programming time versus run time).